# How to crosstab this table with pandas?

Tags: pandas, crosstab, data-science

I have this data and i want to cross-tabulate between the GDP level (above average vs. below average) vs. Level of alcohol consumption (above average vs. below average). and find the correlation.

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dqjF.png)

I'm trying this but is not what i want.

```
pd.crosstab(df['GDP'],df['Recorded_Consupmtion'], margins=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df['GDP_Avg'] = np.where(df.GDP < df.GDP.mean(),'Below Average','Above Average')

df['RC_Avg'] = np.where(df.Recorded_Consupmtion < df.Recorded_Consupmtion.mean(),'Below Average','Above Average')

pd.crosstab(df['GDP_Avg'],df['RC_Avg'], margins=True)
```

Output:

```
RC_Avg         Above Average  Below Average  All
GDP_Avg                                         
Above Average              5              0    5
Below Average              1              3    4
All                        6              3    9
```